# The tire is flat(AmE)

Tags: word-usage

Can I use:

> The car has started going a bit out of control, I guess the tyre is flat.

Is this sentence natural in AmE

Comment: I removed the picture.  We know what a flat tire/tyre is.

Answer (score 1):

In US English we spell it "tire" instead of "tyre". But otherwise, that wording sounds OK.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the "tire is flat".

Saying "the car has started to go a bit out of control" is odd.  Going "out of control" is a major failure of a car, and usually results in a serious crash in a matter of seconds.

A tire suddenly going flat when you are driving fast could cause the car to go out of control, but you would not then have time to say anything but "Aaagh!"

If you drove off with a completely flat tire, you would hear it before you got fast enough to do anything (been there, done that)

You might mean say "the handling is heavy", "the car isn't driving straight". These are possible symptoms of low pressure in a tire.